# Running queue with load balancer Laravel

Tags: laravel, queue

I am using a **load balancer** and 2 servers use the **database** to listen for jobs. The problem is that when I **dispatch a job** and it get picked by a server but it is not completed before the retry time runs out of a queue job, it will start running on the second server and fail with a message saying that the '***Job has attempted to run to many times or run for too long***'. But the first server continues to complete the job and it finishes successfully. I tried everything, starting from using `Queue::before`, writing functions to handle the logic for a job that is in progress but I had no luck, maybe someone can help. Thank you in advance.